# (Flask-SQLAlchemy) How can I check if multiple columns are LIKE a value?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried to match all users that have the value of `'user_like'` in their `username` or `tag` by using filter with multiple arguments but it didn't work :

```py
matched_users = User.query.filter(
      User.username.like(f'%{user_like}%'),
      User.tag.like(f'%{user_like}%')
    ).all()
```

I searched but didn't find any way of doing so, thanks for your help

Comment: @YaakovBressler Oh yeah that helps a lot, I feel dumb that I didn't think about the or operator, thank you !

Comment: That's ok, we're all here to learn.